# Set img src with Javascript in phpBB BBCode

Tags: javascript, bbcode, phpbb

So I currently have the following html bbcode in phpBB3:

```
<a href="http://vbox7.com/play:{INTTEXT}" target="_blank">
<img src="http://i49.vbox7.com/i/{INTTEXT}/{INTTEXT}3.jpg" alt="Vbox7 video" />
</a>
```

This BBCode displays an image of a video with a link to watch it.
However it currently doesn't work, because in the image src, the first parameter must be only the first 3 characters from {INTTEXT}

In PHP, I would get them using `substr($code, 0, 3)`, but here I cannot do that.

I was thinking of doing something similar using javascript, but cannot figure it out.

So far I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = "{INTTEXT}";
var res = str.substring(0, 3)
</script>
```

How to set `res` as the first variable in image's src?

Comment: var str = "someProcessedString"; document.getElementById('imgTagId').attributes["src"].value = str;

Comment: Thank you, this way it worked. Should I post the final code for reference if anybody needs something like that?